# matlab code slowing down while loading netcdf data

Tags: matlab, netcdf

**The code**:

I have to make some plots of the data contained in a big netcdf file with size `1080*171*52*120` (longitude,latitude,depth,time). My strategy it to load the data by 12 chunks in the first and 36 in the fourth dimensions (see *script at the end*).

So, I have a `for` loop on the 12 spatial chunks that contains a `for` loop on the 36 time chunks. At each iteration on the time chunks, I store the information that I need in a matrix `V` and then do the plot.

**The problem:**

The speed of the code seems to slow down after few iterations. At which iteration it happens is not constant... typically 5 or 8. The slowing down does not seem to be due to a memory problem because the memory allocated is constant after the first iteration. The problem seems due to the loading of the data (*via* `ncread`). However, the size of the data that I upload is constant for all the iterations...

Here' the output of `memory` *before the slowing down* together with the elapsed time for loading the files:

> Maximum possible array:       23186 MB (2.431e+10 bytes) * Memory
>   available for all arrays:       23186 MB (2.431e+10 bytes) * Memory
>   used by MATLAB:        1226 MB (1.286e+09 bytes) Physical Memory
>   (RAM):       16296 MB (1.709e+10 bytes)
>
> - Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available. Elapsed time is **0.384304** seconds.

while here the same output *after the slowing down*:

> Maximum possible array:       23186 MB (2.431e+10 bytes) 
>   * Memory available for all arrays:       23186 MB (2.431e+10 bytes) 
>   * Memory used by MATLAB:        1226 MB (1.286e+09 bytes) Physical Memory (RAM):       16296 MB (1.709e+10 bytes)
>
> - Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.  Elapsed time is **26.155781** seconds.

**To confuse thing further...**

Every time chunk is made of 5 time points. The indices of these time points are stored 5 by 5 in each cell of a cell array (`new_inds`) that has 120/5 elements.
However, if I limit the length of this cell array to 8 (or 8*5 time points) the code does not slow down.

In fact, the loading time in this last case is actually constant throughout the execution:

> Maximum possible array:       23068 MB (2.419e+10 bytes) * Memory
>   available for all arrays:       23068 MB (2.419e+10 bytes) * Memory
>   used by MATLAB:        1231 MB (1.291e+09 bytes) Physical Memory
>   (RAM):       16296 MB (1.709e+10 bytes)
>
> - Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available. Elapsed time is **0.390843** seconds.

Please note that in this last case the size of chunks to be uploaded is the same as before. So, even if I obviously expected the code to run faster overall (as there are fewer time points in total), I do not understand why the loading works well in this last case.

**The question:**

The only thing that changes between the two cases is the length of the cell array containing the time indices. But I really doubt that this can be the reason of the slowing down... Also because in the first case matlab gets lazy after a not constant number of iteration.

Can someone understand the reason for it?

**Script:**

```
TT=length(new_inds);%how many time steps to average at each iteration

%%%plotting by chunk
figure;hold on

for kkk=1:numel(chunks)-1   %iteration on space
V=0;   %matrix to update after each iteration on time    

for ttt=1:TT   %iteration on time

fprintf(['LOADING -',num2str(ttt),'/',num2str(TT),'- STARTED!\r'])

s=chunks(kkk+1)-chunks(kkk) %size in space of the current chunk
t=new_inds{ttt}(end)-new_inds{ttt}(1)+1  %size in time of the current chunk
memory 
tic 
%load the velocitites on the current chunk
Uvel=ncread(uvelnc,'Uvel',[chunks(kkk) 1 1 new_inds{ttt}(1)],...
    [chunks(kkk+1)-chunks(kkk)+2 y2 Inf new_inds{ttt}(end)-new_inds{ttt}(1)+1]);

Vvel=ncread(vvelnc,'Vvel',[chunks(kkk) 1 1 new_inds{ttt}(1)],...
    [chunks(kkk+1)-chunks(kkk)+2 y2 Inf new_inds{ttt}(end)-new_inds{ttt}(1)+1]);

Uvel(Uvel==-9999)=NaN;
Vvel(Vvel==-9999)=NaN;
toc

fprintf(['LOADING -',num2str(ttt),'/',num2str(TT),'- DONE!\r'])


%%%velocity module
Uvel= nansum(Uvel,4);
Vvel= nansum(Vvel,4);

[Xv,Yv,Zv]=ndgrid(lonMv(chunks(kkk):chunks(kkk+1)-1+2),latMv(1,:),uv_levs);
[Xu,Yu,Zu]=ndgrid(lonMu(chunks(kkk):chunks(kkk+1)-1+2),latMu(1,:),uv_levs);
Vvel=interpn(Xv,Yv,Zv,Vvel,Xu,Yu,Zu,'linear',NaN);

V = V + sqrt(Uvel.^2+Vvel.^2); %update the matrix V
end %of the iteration on time


V_t=V/sum(cellfun('length',new_inds)); %average V on time

%%%plotting
V_t=V_t(:,:,1); %surface values

lonP=lonMu(chunks(kkk):chunks(kkk+1)-1+2,:);
lonP(V_t==0)=NaN;
latP=latMu(chunks(kkk):chunks(kkk+1)-1+2,:);
m_pcolor(lonP,latP,V_t); 

end %iteration on space
```

Comment: This may (or may not) be the same issue discussed at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13803-matlab-slowing-down-while-reading-netcdf

Answer (score 1):

Use a low-level function `netcdf.getVar` might help

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.